# Changing order of data in database with js and php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I am not sure if the title is 100% accurate, but here's my problem.

I have a website where n user can upload images, I want to enable the user to order the images he has uploaded and save them in that order and later preview them in the exact order.

The ordering can be done same time as the upload or later on.
 I am using plupload. My idea is to save the source of every image in the database with an additional column that would represent order number and use `ORDER BY` when getting the images.

But for every new image I have to check the number of images I already have and that many SQL request will be too slow. And with the adding of new images and rearranging them come a lot of `UPDATE` statements that also slows the database.
And this means that I will also have to check the old place and new of every image and change it if I have to, which meant more SQL statements.

All of this didn't seem like a good approach so I was wondering if I could get some pointers on a different approach or optimization. But I would like to keep plupload if possible.

Comment: Your question seems to come from **come a lot of UPDATE statements that also slows the database.**. Are you sure this is the case? A simple update when uploading a file should be neglectible comparing to the actual uploading. Don't worry about it, and just update it.

Answer (score 0):

Normally an `ORDER BY $order` is sufficient using values like 0,1,2,3  with default 0 and where lowest is first.

If you really not want to make any changes to your own DB you can consider writing a code so that it uses the local storage on the client's side.
But this would result in that when the users makes access from another computer, that data will not be available.

So whatever option is going to be given, still the best is to use your own db for it.
When your code is written well, there should not be any problem at all to run these queries.

Comment: I would use my own db, but I am not very fond of using that much statements and the order will be as you sad 0,1,2 etc.
But I will be expecting 100+ photos and having all that in doesn't seem quite good of an option.

Comment: It needs to call the db anyway to lookup the images....right? so at the end it only populates them by the extra field, there is no extra query need...all is done in one query.The updating a value from example order number 3 to order number 11 and 11 to 3... that is peanuts for your db.

Comment: Unless... and i think that is what you have in mind... is that it with every order change... fixing all the other values.... yes then it can make an overload.... but why you should do that?

Comment: But even if would do it like that , still 100+ means nothing for the db.If have 1000 users on a cheap server and do it all simultaneous, then it can give overhead.Do not break your head on it.Have a little trust in your DB :)

Comment: Well I would have to change every because the change is not like img 2 and img 5 change places but put img 12 in front of img 2 (between 1 and 2) and form img 2 till the end I would have to change everything. My bad, sorry for not mentioning this earlier.